# Confusion with Jstl tag c:forEach items

Tags: java, spring, jstl

I have a confusion about c:forEach items="${} JSTL tag.
I have a category of items, filled with some articles T wanna show those articles by category and I couldn't figure out how to do so in the jsp file knowing that everything that precedes works perfectly fine.
I am able to show categories with c:forEach items="${categories}, and articles with c:forEach items="${articles}, and now I wanna show the articles that belong to one category, I tried c:forEach items="${categorie.articles} but nothing.

DAOImpl

```
// Articles by category
    @Override
    public List<Article> articleParCategorie(Long idCat) 
    {
        Query req = em.createQuery("select a from Article a where a.categorie.idCategorie=:x");
        req.setParameter("x", idCat);
        return req.getResultList();
    }
```

Controller

```
// Action for articles by category
                    @RequestMapping(value="/ConsultCat")
                    public String ArtParCat(Long idCat, Model model)
                    {
                        model.addAttribute("categories", metier.listCategories());
                        model.addAttribute("articles", metier.articleParCategorie(idCat));
                        return "ArticleParCat";
                    }
```

JSP file
this is what i tried, it returns the view but with no categories or articles

```
<c:forEach items="${categorie.articles}" var="cat">
                                <div class="col align-center">

                                    <!-- Le nom de la catégorie a partir de la base donnée -->
                                            ${cat.article.titre}

                                            <!-- La description de la catégorie a partir de la base donnée -->                  
                                            <p>${cat.description}</p>


                                </div>
                                </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Where is `categorie` defined? Where does it come from? What's the code of its class?

Answer (score 0):

the code in both Class category and Class Article, and code in the view ListCategories (which returns the categories perfectly).

Categorie Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CATEGORIE")
public class Categorie implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idCategorie;
    private String nomCategorie;
    private String description;
    private byte [] photoCat;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="categorie")
    private Collection<Article> articles;
```

Article Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ARTICLE")
public class Article implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idArticle;
    private String titre;
    private String texte;
    private Date date;
    private byte [] photo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_CAT")
    private Categorie categorie;
```

The list of categories View :

```
<!-- Les catégories -->
                            <div class="flex flex-3">

                                <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="cat">
                                <div class="col align-center">

                                    <div class="image round fit">

                                            <!-- L'image de la catégories a partir de la base donnée -->
                                            <img src="photoCat?idCat=${cat.idCategorie}">
                                    </div>
                                            <!-- Le nom de la catégorie a partir de la base donnée -->
                                            ${cat.nomCategorie}

                                            <!-- La description de la catégorie a partir de la base donnée -->                  
                                            <p>${cat.description}</p>



                                            <!-- Les bouttons supprimer modifier qui devront être visible qu'aux adminisrateurs -->
                                            <a href="ConsultCat?idCategorie=${cat.idCategorie}" class="btn btn-default" id="Goto">See more</a>

                                            <a href="editCat?idCat=${cat.idCategorie}" class="btn btn-default" id="edit">edit</a>                                           
                                            <a href="suppCat?idCat=${cat.idCategorie}" class="btn btn-default" id="delete">delete</a>






                                </div>
                                </c:forEach>
```